# Major problem with duplicate payment authorizations/charges

Tags: paypal, duplicate, stripe, authorize

```
Magento 2.4.2p-1
Amasty Stripe extension
Paypal
```

We used the Magento Migration tool to migrate from Magento 1.9 to 2.4.2 p1. Ever since the beginning, we had various problems including first with Paypal where customers would get multiple authorizations with just 1 order. We then installed and configured the Stripe Payment extension from Amasty and the same issue occurs where some customers work fine and others will get multiple either authorizations or charges (depending if it's set to authorize or capture in the Admin panel). Some customers get charged as many as 6 times for 1 order which creates a major issue. Occasionally, there is a charge in the back-end of Stripe and no order.

The fact that this happens with 2 different payment providers makes me believe it is a Magento issue. We were able to replicate this once when a colleague of mine was placing a test order and got an Error that there was something wrong with the phone number and then a duplicate charge was submitted.

**How can we diagonse and fix this?**

UPDATED:

*This tends to come in batches* and **there is never an order created in Magento!** One customer recently had 6 charges on his credit card and most recently, there were 2 Cancelled transactions for 1 customer and no order either.

*In the payment information in Stripe's back end - it never has a phone number or Email address. Somehow, this all appears to be somehow related to not capturing the phone number/Email?*

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @Afzal Arshad - The problem appeared to be with the Amasty One-step checkout extension. We disabled it and it helped.